# "Meet my boss" or "meet with my boss"?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "meet" and "meet with"?

For example, which of these should I say?

> 1. I met my boss yesterday
> 2. I met with my boss yesterday
> 3. I'm meeting my friends tonight
> 4. I'm meeting with my friends tonight

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I met my boss yesterday.

Without elaboration, this implies that you met your boss for the first time.

> I met my boss at Spago<sup>*</sup> yesterday.

You had lunch or dinner with your boss. (It was not your first encounter.)

> I met with my boss yesterday.

You got together with your boss for a specific purpose. It was likely to be a working meeting of some sort.

> I'm meeting my friends tonight.

You're going out to have fun with your friends.

> I'm meeting with my friends tonight.

You're getting together with friends for some shared purpose. It might be for fun, but the "with" is more likely to be used to suggest a special purpose to the meeting: planning, hobby, whatever.

<sup>*</sup> *Spago is an upscale restaurant, suitable for business luncheons or important dinners.*

Comment: To clarify, "I met my boss at Spago yesterday." does *not* necessarily imply you met your boss for the first time at a place called Spago.

Comment: @BruceWayne: I thought that was implicit, but no harm in making it explicit.

Comment: "I met my boss at Spago yesterday." implies that the meeting was unplanned, or even unexpected, especially if "Spago" is a grocery store, or some other place unrelated to business functions. Lunch/dinner plans are often expressed as, "I had lunch with my boss yesteraday." But, "I met my boss at the cafe" does not imply whether the meeting was planned or unplanned without more context.

Comment: @jpaugh: [Spago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spago) is an upscale restaurant, suitable for business luncheons or important dinners. The sentence does not carry the implication that the meeting was unplanned. More likely it was for a promotion or some good thing.

Comment: @Robusto Got it. If I had known of the place, that would have supplied the missing context. I would include that link in the answer. With it, your explanation makes sense. (Without it, readers may get a bit confused, whether fluent or not.)

Comment: i've heard *ran into* used to mean meeting someone coincidentally. *i ran into my boss at Spago* means you both happened to be at at the same restaurant. *i met my boss at Spago* still carries the implication that this is the first time you've met them; it's not that crazy to really wine and dine a (potential) new hire depending on the industry or the job.

Comment: Note that traditionalists, certainly in the UK, regard "meet with" as ugly (because the "with" is redundant), and regard "meet up with" as an absolute horror.